# In App Purchase Issue in iOS 9

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios9, ios-9-beta3

I am using In App Purchase in My App,which is working fine on all iOS version except iOS 9.The Purchase is showing successful But control is not return in Delegate function.the Following text is printing in command:

HangTracer interval is 0, forcing to 1s, while using Contact Framework